# Laravel 5.1 Redis cache

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm trying to implement a very basic caching mechanism into my Laravel app.

I installed Redis, started it via terminal (src/redis-server) and changed cache from file to redis in Laravel's config file, but it takes LONGER (1s vs 2s) than regular query when I use cache.

Am I missing something here? I just want to cache a query for 10 minutes.

Here's my FeedController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\Feed;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Company;
use Redis;
use Cache;


class FeedController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        if (Cache::has('companies')) {
            // cache exists.
            $companies = Cache::get("companies");
        } else {
            // cache doesn't exist, create a new one
            $companies = Cache::remember("companies",10, function() {
                return Company::all();
            });

            Cache::put("companies", $companies, 10);
        }


        return view('index')->with('companies', $companies)
    }
```

My view

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
    {{$company->name}}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, caching isn't always faster. Second, you're double checking the cache.

You can just use:

```
$companies = Cache::remember("companies",10, function() {
            return Company::all();
        });
```

It checks of the cache item exist, and if not it will execute the closure and cache the result in the specified key. The cache:has if/else is unnecessary and will only slow it down.

Comment: I am a redis noob, care to explain why caching isn't always faster?

Comment: Imagine the following situation:

    $data = Cache::remember('data', 10, function() {
        return  [1, 2, 3, 4];
    });

This is an extreme example, but generating the array in PHP is way faster than fetching it from the cache. You should always consider when to use it.
When MySQL is configured the right way it's easier, possibly faster and more reliable to just get the items from MySQL. Especially on simple queries. 

You should use caching when performance becomes an issue, before that, don't really bother.